# Doubts about the differentiability of a function with absolute value

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R^{2}}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by: $f(x,y)=|x|(xy^{2}+|x|)$. The question is to study the differentiability of $f$. I rewrited: $f(x,y)=|x|xy^{2}+x^{2}$ for simplicity. I noted that we may have problems of differentiability when $x=0$, geometrically: above the $y$-axis. We know that $f(x,y)$ is differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$ iff $lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (x_0,y_0)}\frac{[f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)]}{\sqrt{(x-x_0)^{2}+(y-y_0)^{2}}}=0$. The problem is clear: we have infinitely many points to check I think. As a tentative I tried to study the differentiability of $f$ at $(0,0)$. The partial derivatives have value $0=f(0,0)$ so we get: $lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{|x|xy^{2}+x^{2}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}=0$. This is not clearly working with polar coordinates, but I think it's not true that the limit is $0$ and so we have $f$ not differentiable at the Origin. Still, even if I proved this I'm still confused about the infinite many points to check.

Comment: You can check infinitely many points at once.

Comment: Ok, but how ? Simply inserting a parameter such as $t$ in the $(0,t)$ and computing the limit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $g(x)=x|x|=\operatorname{sgn(x)}x^2$ is derivable and continuous everywhere since $\pm\ 2x\to 0$ in zero.

From there $f$ is an additive multiplicative composition of $C^1$ functions, namely $x^2,\ x|x|$ and $y^2$ so is itself $C^1$.

Comment: Thanks, I understood that your answer is correct because a friend suggested that being $C^{1}\rightarrow$ being differentiable by a theorem we call "Teorema del differenziale totale"; in english: "Total differential theorem".

Answer (score 1):

We're trying to find:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\dfrac{|x|xy^{2}+x^{2}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}$$

Let's write it as:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}
|x|x \times \dfrac{y^{2}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}
+
\dfrac{x^{2}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}
= \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} f(x, y)\times g(x, y) + h(x,y)
$$

It is clear that all of $f, g, h \to 0$ as $x, y \to 0$. Hence the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The function is $$f(x,y)=|x|\left( x y^2 +|x| \right) = x^2\ \left(1 + y^2 \ \text{sign}(x)\right)=\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 x^2 \left(y^2+1\right) & x\geq 0 \\
 x^2 \left(1-y^2\right) & x<0 \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}$$

A discontiunuity is exhibited in the 2.derivative wrt x is along the line x=0,

$$\partial_{x,x}f(x,y)=\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 -2 \left(y^2-1\right) & x<0 \\
 2 \left(y^2+1\right) & x>0 \\
 \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}$$